# Why do SURF feature points have floating point coordinates?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, feature-detection, feature-extraction

I have just written the C++ OpenCV 2.4.7 code to extract feature points in stereo images using SurfFeatureDetector. It worked well but I got confused when I realized that the point coordinates are floating points, say for example it found coordinates [283.23 123.424] as one of the features in left image.

Here is a part of the code (simply extracting features):

```
int minHessian = 400;

SurfFeatureDetector detector(minHessian);
vector<KeyPoint> featuresLeft, featuresRight;

detector.detect(leftImg, featuresLeft);
detector.detect(rightImg, featuresRight);
```

Can anyone please tell me how this could be happening?
Is there any interpolation involved in the built-in functions?

Comment: Many of the algorithms in OpenCV operate on floating point versions of the original images, this is not unexpected. Both SIFT and SURF interpolate for an accurate position of features. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform#Interpolation_of_nearby_data_for_accurate_position) for details.